# Creating a table with the coefficients of multiple linear models in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have 4 models (I actually have 9 or 10). Most of their independent variables are overlapping, but some are different. I'd like to create a table showing all their coefficient estimates side by side, with suitable blank spaces for variables that don't appear in some models.

```
M1 <- lm(y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + W1)  
M2 <- lm(y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + W2)  
M3 <- lm(y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + W1 + W2)  
M4 <- lm(y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + W3)
```

I'd like a table that looks like this:

```
| Coefs| M1 | sig. | M2 | sig. | M3 | sig. | M4 | sig. |
|------|----|------|----|------|----|------|----|------|
| V1   | xx | *    |xx  |*     |xx  |*     |xx  |*     |
| V2   | xx | *    |xx  |*     |xx  |*     |xx  |*     |
| V3   | xx | *    |xx  |*     |xx  |*     |xx  |*     |
| W1   | xx | *    |    |      |xx  |*     |    |      |
| W2   |    |      |xx  |*     |xx  |*     |    |      |
| W3   |    |      |    |      |    |      |xx  |*     |
```

I feel like I see this kind of table in journal papers often, so I've been looking around for a solution, maybe using broom somehow, but haven't been able to work it out. I don't mind if the empty spots are  blank or padded with NAs or something.

Edit: despite that I really did look before, I found now that there are several packages that can easily produce this kind of regression table if one is looking for a 'pretty' table for publication, eg. huxtable or gtsummary. But I appreciate the provided answer as more of a raw and flexible approach to the problem.

Comment: Read carefully chapter 35 of "R for Data Science" https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html. This should take you to the next level in R and solve your problem elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

I made data `dummy` for an example.

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  y = c(1:20),
  V1 = rnorm(20,4,5),
  V2 = rnorm(20, 0, 1),
  V3 = rnorm(20, 0, 1),
  W1 = rnorm(20, 10, 1),
  W2 = rnorm(20,1,5),
  W3 = rnorm(20,1,1)
)
```

Then make model `M1` to `M4`

```
M1 <- lm(y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + W1, data = dummy)  
M2 <- lm(y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + W2, data = dummy)  
M3 <- lm(y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + W1 + W2, data = dummy)  
M4 <- lm(y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + W3, data = dummy)
```

Then extract coefficients you wanted

```
MM1 <- summary(M1)$coefficients %>% as.data.frame %>% rownames_to_column() %>% select(rowname, Estimate, `Std. Error`) %>%
  rename(M1 = Estimate, sig.M1 = `Std. Error`)
MM2 <- summary(M2)$coefficients %>% as.data.frame %>% rownames_to_column() %>% select(rowname, Estimate, `Std. Error`) %>%
  rename(M2 = Estimate, sig.M2 = `Std. Error`)
MM3 <- summary(M3)$coefficients %>% as.data.frame %>% rownames_to_column() %>% select(rowname, Estimate, `Std. Error`) %>%
  rename(M3 = Estimate, sig.M3 = `Std. Error`)
MM4 <- summary(M4)$coefficients %>% as.data.frame %>% rownames_to_column() %>% select(rowname, Estimate, `Std. Error`) %>%
  rename(M4 = Estimate, sig.M4 = `Std. Error`)
```

Finally combine them using `reduce` and `full_join`

```
list(MM1,MM2,MM3,MM4) %>% reduce(full_join, by = "rowname")

      rowname         M1     sig.M1         M2    sig.M2         M3     sig.M3          M4    sig.M4
1 (Intercept) 25.6300409 17.0743452 10.9236902 1.8473586 24.7528332 19.6171238 11.66706138 2.0336288
2          V1 -0.1973380  0.2910641 -0.1717022 0.3017712 -0.2051194  0.3105196 -0.08143169 0.2819991
3          V2 -0.1001076  1.4811114 -0.1607587 1.5116289 -0.1143781  1.5387822 -0.06223230 1.4828105
4          V3  0.4616137  1.7851494 -0.1506603 1.6604661  0.4278893  1.8759727  0.08994041 1.6600729
5          W1 -1.4039157  1.6159054         NA        NA -1.3193849  1.8629899          NA        NA
6          W2         NA         NA  0.1419206 0.3016012  0.0351603  0.3417814          NA        NA
7          W3         NA         NA         NA        NA         NA         NA -1.25253787 1.4603211
```

Comment: Thanks, that's cool, but ideally would have Estimate.M1 rather than Estimate.x (without just renaming them manually)

Comment: @JRR I'm sorry I miss that. I edit my code.